# Confusion in tortoise svn - switching

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am confused in the concept of switching (using tortoise svn). We are a team of 3 developers and I am Dev2 here.

Firstly, I tried switching using following steps (lets say, currently working on trunk and want to start work in branches v1.0)

1. Right click on /branches/v1.0
2. Choose tortoisesvn - switch
3. To Path: /branches/v1.0

   - Head Revision (checked)
   - Switch Depth : Working Copy

**Please let me know if I am doing something wrong in above?**

But, after that I skipped the switching and then our working gives us following output:

1. All the developers worked in trunk and then development is over
2. Created a tag with v1.0
3. Found bugs in tag v1.0 so created a branch v1.0 from tag v1.0
4. Need new features as well so Dev1 (Developer 1) continues working in trunk where Dev2 and Dev3 are working on branch v1.0
5. Dev2 writes code in branch v1.0 and commits
6. Dev3 get updates in branch (got updates of Dev1) and then writes code in branch v1.0 and commits
7. Dev1 get updates in branch (got updates of Dev2 and Dev3)
8. Dev2 and Dev3 get updates in trunk (got updates from Dev1)

**All is working fine without switching then what is the concept of switching?**

**Also, what will happen if I have uncommitted files in trunk while switching?**

Answer (score 3):

Imagine if you were working on trunk, and suddenly realized you should have been working on branch 2.3. You could checkout branch 2.3, but you'll lose all of your work. You could try duplicating it, but that could take a long time.

Switching allows you to *switch* the base of your local copy without losing any of your work. Files you modified will still contain your modifications. Files you added will still be added. Files you deleted will still be deleted.

```
$ svn co $REPO/trunk/proj1
[...work...work...work...]   #Whoops! Should have been on Release 2.3 branch!
# svn switch $REPO/branches/2.3/proj1
[...work...work...work...]   #Everything is fine and dandy!
```

Some people use switch to switch their working copy without having to do another checkout. For example, I finish my work on `proj1`, and now I have some work on the Release 2.3 branch. I simply switch to that branch and save time because I don't have to redownload everything. Plus , I save space!

I highly discourage that thinking because you can easily get confused what your working directory is representing. I've seen some convoluted prompts to extract the branch information and display it in the prompt. However, I name my checkout after my project and branch (or trunk) and I use a separate working directory for each and every project.

Speed shouldn't be an issue. It takes five to ten minutes to do a checkout of a really big Subversion project -- just enough time to get a cup of coffee. Nor, in this era of gigabyte disk sizes, should space be a premium. Using `svn switch` should not be a common occurrence.

At one time, you sometimes switched if the server that hosted your repository changed. However, there's now a special `svn relocate` command just for that purpose:

```
$ svn co svn://repo/proj1   # We were using svnserve
$ svn relocate svn://repo http://repo/svn  #Now we're using Apache https
$ svn relocate http://repo/svn/proj1       #Alternative to the above.
```

Comment: The TortoiseSVN doc says that `switch` can be in lieu of `checkout` but that just seems odd to me. What we do here is checkout at the branches/tags/trunk level.  If I need to add an experimental feature I create a branch from trunk and then do an `update` in the branches folder and work on the files there.  Yea I am creating duplicate copies of all my files but space is cheap and I never get confused on where my working copy is pointed.  Other than killing more bits, do you see any downside to doing things this way? I've not seen it explicitly advocated so it has me wondering.

Comment: I use separate working directories for each branch just like you do. Back when we had 10Mb disks and space was a premium, I could see using switch a lot. However, when a PC comes with a 125Gb of space, is considered small, having multiple working directories isn't an issue. Even the biggest projects rarely take up more than 10Mb of space. Where an issue might occur is that binaries can be fairly large. We have a project that produces about 10 gigabytes of compiled code. In that case, clean out the compiled code.

Answer (score 2):

svn switch should just update your local checkout to point to a new location on the server. e.g. if someone has moved folders around in the repository.

Any uncommitted files should be fine - **a switch is just a change to the local file system**. After the switch when you view diffs or similar, it will be pointing to the new repository.